# Move leaflet polygon to given position

Tags: javascript, polygon, leaflet, geolocation

I have a circle and a polygon that I'd like to move to the user's local position. I managed to move the circle latLng but I can't find a way to do the same thing with a polygon.

Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building on what @ghybs suggests, here is some javascript to get a users position and translate a polygon (in this case a triangle) to be centered on the users position

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/w1q0bLtg/2/)

```
var map = L.map('map').setView([0,0], 5);
L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png').addTo(map);

var poly = L.polygon([[30,-15],[35,-12.5],[36,-18]]).addTo(map);
var center = poly.getBounds().getCenter();
var points = poly.getLatLngs();
var offsets = []
for (var i = 0; i < points.length; i++)  {
    var point = [];
    point.push(points[i].lat - center.lat);
    point.push(points[i].lng - center.lng);
    offsets.push(point);
}

function showMap(position) {
    var lat = position.coords.latitude;
    var lng = position.coords.longitude;

    var marker = L.marker([lat,lng]).addTo(map);
    map.panTo([lat,lng]);
    var newpoints = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < offsets.length; i++)  {
        var point = [];
        point.push(lat + offsets[i][0]);
        point.push(lng + offsets[i][1]);
        newpoints.push(point);
        }
    L.polygon(newpoints).addTo(map);

}

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showMap);
```

Comment: Hi @toms! You linked the wrong fiddle but thanks a lot for your piece of code!!!!! It creates two polys but this is fixed removing _.addTo(map)_ where _var poly_ is declared!

Answer (score 2):

You know that a circle in Leaflet is defined by a unique LatLng coordinate + radius, whereas a polygon is made of several LatLng coordinates.

That is why it is trivial to say "the circle is at *this* LatLng position". And it is trivial to center that circle on a user position.

But we are left with plenty options for the polygon: how should we compute its "position", since it is defined by *many* LatLng coordinates?

If your polygon is already defined around the [0, 0] position, then you could translate all its vertices (i.e. all its LatLng coordinates) by the user position.

Otherwise, you have to chose a "centre" (the most trivial would be the barycentre / centroid of its vertices), so that you can compute the difference with the user position, then translate all the polygon vertices like above by this difference.